# cdn behavior for multiple urls mapping to the same result file

Tags: cdn, akamai

Assume that I have a http service which serves some contents, and I want to place cdn in front of it to serve cached content. the issue is, the url can take parameters, and mulitiple parameters maps to one result file, will cdn be efficient in this case?  will cdn cache a different copy of the file for each of the strings that map to the same file?

For example:

http://myservice.com/getlogfile?time=10000
to
http://myservice.com/getlogfile?time=19999

all above maps to log.1

Answer (score 0):

The Akamai cache configuration can be altered to adhere to specified rules. If you would like for one file to be cached for all query strings, simply set your Akamai configuration to ignore query strings. The Akamai Knowledge base found within the Akamai control panel contains a document called 'Edge Server Configuration Guide' that explains this configuration in detail. Start with the section called 'Ignore Query Strings' (page 104).